# Error: Cannot find an overload for "restore" and the argument count: "1"

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting this error from the following code. It's coming from $Context.Load($RecycleBinItems). Any idea what's wrong with the code? I am attempting to restore all recyclebin items.

---

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\3.17.2001.2\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\3.17.2001.2\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Import-Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'

#Get the Site Owners Credentials to connect the SharePoint
$SiteUrl = "https://phaselinknet.sharepoint.com"
$UserName = Read-host "Enter the Email ID"  
$Password = Read-host - assecurestring "Enter Password for $AdminUserName"  
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password)  

# Once Connected, get the Site information using current Context objects
Try {  
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)  
    $Context.Credentials = $Credentials
    $Site = $Context.Site  
    $RecycleBinItems = $Site.RecycleBin  
    $Context.Load($Site)  
    $Context.Load($RecycleBinItems)  
    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 
    Write-Host "Total Number of Files found in Recycle Bin:" $RecycleBinItems.Count
}

catch {  
    write - host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" - foregroundcolor Red  
}

# using for loop to restore the item one by one  
Try {

    if($RecycleBinItems)
    {
     foreach($Item in $RecycleBinItems)
        {
            $Site.RecycleBin.restore($Item.ID)
            #Write-Host "Item restored:"$Item.Title
        }
    }
}

catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving you you answer. There is not a version of the method Restore that takes 1 parameter.

You need to load up a list of items simular to this

```
$Item = $RecycleBin | Where{$_.Title -eq $ItemName}
```

Then call restore for the items.

```
if($Item -ne $null)
{
 $Item.Restore()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. So I load up the first 10 items in the recyclebin, and Write-Host does write out the correct files, but the $Item.Restore() does noting as the files are still not restored:

```
$itemsToRestore = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
{
    $Item = $RecycleBinItems[$i]
    $itemsToRestore += $Item
}
Write-Host "Total Number of Files to Restore:" $itemsToRestore.Count

foreach($item in $itemsToRestore) 
{
    Write-Host "Item:" $Item.Title
    $item.Restore()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I missed $Context.ExecuteQuery() after $Item.Restore(). It works now.